# How to structure a DocumentDB Database

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I am completely new to NoSQL, so I may just have a basic misunderstanding...

I went through [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angularfire-realtime-slack-clone) that teaches how to make a chat app using Firebase. As an example, the JSON for a direct message chat would look like this:

```
{
  "userMessages": {
    "userid1": {
      "userid2": {
        "messageId1": {
          "uid": "userid1",
          "body": "Hello!",
          "timestamp": firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        },
        "messageId2": {
          "uid": "userid2",
          "body": "Hey!",
          "timestamp": firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When requesting the messages, you'd look at userMessages/UserId1/UserId2. This would give all the messages between the two users.

I decided to attempt something similar using DocumentDB, and I'm not sure how to do it. It seems like I should just be able to create a container called UserMessages and put all the data in just as above, but it seems like DocumentDB only allows retrieving and updating top level documents. So in this case, I'd need to get everything under userid1, and anytime I'm adding a message, I'd need to update the entire userid1 document, including all the messages that aren't changing.

The only way I could see making this work is to flatten this design. But flattening the rest of the app (with many more complicated objects) seems like it would require many more containers to be created (each costing money) when I should just be able to have a more layered design and update only the layer I need or push only the additional data that needs to be pushed.

Long story short, do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how NoSQL should be structured, or is DocumentDB just so different from other NoSQL solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documents in DocDB are stored in **Collections**. Collections can hold any kind (schema-free) document and are the billable unit. (See the [Hierarchical model here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-resources)).

You are correct about DocDB when you say you'd need to update the entire document, you cannot do partial updates, so in your original approach, it will turn into a slower process each time a new message arrives.

But you can refactor the design for smaller documents and still query the user1 / user2 relationship with something like:

```
{
    "type":"message",
    "from":"userid1",
    "to":"userid2", 
    "conversation":"userid1-userid2",
    "body":"Hello!":
    "timestamp":firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
}

{
    "type":"message",
    "from":"userid2",
    "to":"userid1", 
    "conversation":"userid1-userid2",
    "body":"Hey!":
    "timestamp":firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
}
```

So you can actually do 2 different queries:

- What is the conversation between user1 and user2 by querying by the `conversation` attribute.
- Which messages were sent by user1 to user2 (or just sent by user1) with the `from` and `to` attribute. You could query for the sent messages by user1 to any user using `from` or those received with just `to`.

If you read [how the internal indexes are managed](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content-nlnl/blob/master/articles/documentdb/documentdb-indexing.md) you can see that all the properties are automatically indexed and there is no performance problem when you flatten the data like this.

I'm not familiar with Firebase, you might need to change some code if the application is expecting the information on the first format (maybe it's a matter of creating some translation middleware).

Hope it helps!